# How to display a textbox for specific time ( 5 seconds)

Tags: java, swt

I am implementing `CTRL+F` functionality for a view in my RCP application.( using SWT widgets)
For that, whenever I press CTRL+F, a small text box is popped up for typing and searching in the view.

But, if I dont enter anything or dont focus anything else, it remains popped up.

I want to display it for just 5 seconds of time.
So, please anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Adding code for more clarification :-

```
final Text findTextBox = new Text(viewer.getTable(), SWT.BORDER);
if ((((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL) && (e.keyCode == 'f'))) {
    Rectangle rect = viewer.getTable().getBounds();
    findTextBox.setVisible(true);
    findTextBox.setFocus();
        findtextBox.setLocation(rect.x + rect.width -120, rect.y + rect.height - 25);
        findTextBox.setSize(120, 25);
    }
```

Comment: Sheetal, you just need a timer. This might you need. Just pass the time how much delay you  want and pass the action to it. In action hide your text box.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552596/timer-in-java-using-eclipse

Comment: Edited the question, added code for more clarification.

Comment: Any feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some code that just utilizes the basic Java libraries and SWT:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
    text.setVisible(false);

    final Runnable timer = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (text.isDisposed())
                return;

            text.setVisible(true);
        }
    };

    display.timerExec(5000, timer);

    shell.pack();
    shell.setSize(400, 200);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```