# How to create a Timer in swt java

Tags: java, timer, swt, repeat

Hi guys I have to create a timer that every 2 seconds repeat a part of my code, can you tell me the code? I don't need the graphic on this timer.

Comment: try multithreading with thread sleep as 2 seconds..

Comment: This might be helpful
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/Createtwooneshottimers2000ms.htm

Comment: A standard way to repeat a task in java can be done using java.util.Timer and java.util.TimerTask

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Timer vs ExecutorService?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409932/java-timer-vs-executorservice)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16111306) should be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 2, 2, TimeUtil.SECONDS);
```

Or you can use `java.util.Timer`.

Or with SWT you can use:

```
Display.getDefault().timerExec(2000, runnable);
```

which guarantees that the runnable will be executed on the user interface thread. With `timerExec` you have to reschedule the runnable each time it runs.

`runnable` is an instance of the `Runnable` class containing the code you want to execute, for example in Java 8 you can use:

```
Runnable runnable = () ->
  {
    browser.refresh();

    Display.getDefault().timerExec(2000, this);
  };
```

for Java 7 and earlier use:

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
 {
   public void run()
   {
     browser.refresh();

     Display.getDefault().timerExec(2000, this);
   }
 };
```

Comment: I have to do this istruction: browser.refresh(); which is the best?

Comment: That sounds like it needs to run on the UI thread, so `Display.timerExec` is best.

Comment: Where I have to put my code?

Comment: You put it at the point where you want to run something 2 seconds later.

Comment: ok, I have to create a runnable variable? because eclipse give me an error

Comment: `timerExec` expects an instance of `Runnable` which you have to create containing the code you want to run.

Comment: Show your code, I use this all the time